# query using FQL on comment with display all the reply

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm using this command to display the comment with reply on my page
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://development.deolvet.com/lorem-ipsum/.

But it will not display the exact comment that I want. I would like to know if anyone can help me here to display all comment with reply on my blog with xid using FQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag setup is misconfigured based on your app settings. As described in the Debug Tool,

> Object at URL 'http://development.deolvet.com/lorem-ipsum/' of type 'article' is invalid because the domain 'development.deolvet.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '102055106604365'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/102055106604365.

Either use a next app as your dev app or change your domain to development.deolvet.com.

Comment: I try it again but still I cannot get the blog comment  with xid value. Or do you have a recommended plugin for wordpress will import those fbcomment with xid specify on my blog to wordpress database?